# How to validate PasswordBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I'm trying to make a validation for a `PasswordBox`. For making validations I followed this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation), that shows how to validate on `TextBox`.

The problem comes with `PasswordBoxes`. Because its `Password` is not bindable due to security reasons, I tried to make a binding following [this link](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html) (also explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37167/Binding-Passwords), for CodeProject users).

So, apparently, fantastic! I can bind my `PasswordBox` with its `Password` property, so then I can bind with my validation. But it ignores me...

This is a regular `TextBox` that I use and works fine:

```
<local:ErrorProvider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
    <TextBox Width="160" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Name="textBoxUserPass" 
           Text="{Binding Path=Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
 </local:ErrorProvider>
```

And this is the `PasswordBox` I tried to simulate:

```
<local:ErrorProvider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
      <PasswordBox Width="160"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Name="textBoxUserPass"
          local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True"
          local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
 </local:ErrorProvider>
```

This is how I get the `BindingExpression` for each `TextBox`:

```
BindingExpression beUserName = textBoxUserName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
if (beUserName != null) beUserName.UpdateSource();
```

And this is how I get it for the `PasswordBox`:

```
BindingExpression bePassword = textBoxUserPass.GetBindingExpression(PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword);
if (bePassword != null) bePassword.UpdateSource();
```

If we made any mistake (defined on my Validation class), when I do this:

```
if (!beUserName.HasError && !bePassword.HasError)
```

each `BindingExpression` should say **true** of **false** depending on error validations. But for my `PasswordBox` never gets the value... Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried setting `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` and `ValidatesOnExceptions=True` on your bindings?

Comment: It doesn't exist for `PasswordBox`...

Comment: It does for the `BoundPassword` attached property: `local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"`

Comment: True, it worked! Could you please post answer as this is the exact solution for this case?

Comment: where is this PasswordBoxAssistant that everyone seems to be using?

Comment: PasswordBoxAssistant:
http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` and `ValidatesOnExceptions=True` on your binding:

```
<PasswordBox ...
   local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password,
      UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, 
      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
      ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set Mode=TwoWay on your binding

```
local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password,Mode=TwoWay,
UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, the only way to add validation on a PasswordBox is to throw a new ValidationException in the setter of the binding property for SecurePassword. The PasswordBoxAssistant will not help you with this.

Comment: Hummm can you provide an example or link? It sounds as a solution.

Comment: This is what I found in an old app that I was working on:public SecureString NewPassword
        {
            get
            {
                return _newPassword;
            }
            set
            {
                _newPassword = value;
                string error = IsPasswordValid();                
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(error);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Hummm, gonna try it, but the exact solution is the one Richard Deeming posted (for this case). But I'm gonna try this one too, as I have this particular case also at my code.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, without using any "unsecure" string in the middle, is to adapt the Window code, something like this:

Let's suppose I have an MVVM object like this, with WPF validation using [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx):

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    ...
    public SecureString SecurePassword
    {
        get
        { ... }
        set
        {
            ...
            OnPropertyChanged("SecurePassword");
        }
    }

    ...

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return Validate(null); } }
    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName] { get { return Validate(columnName); } }

    private string Validate(string memberName)
    {
        string error = null;
        ...
        if (memberName == "SecurePassword" || memberName == null)
        {
            // this is where I code my custom business rule
            if (SecurePassword == null || SecurePassword.Length == 0)
            {
                error = "Password must be specified.";
            }
        }
        ...
        return error;
    }

}
```

And a Window Xaml with a PasswordBox like this:

```
<PasswordBox Name="MyPassword" PasswordChanged="MyPassword_Changed" ... />
```

Then, the corresponding Window code like this will trigger PasswordBox binding:

```
// add a custom DependencyProperty
public static readonly DependencyProperty SecurePasswordProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SecurePassword", typeof(SecureString), typeof(MyWindow));

public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = myObject; // created somewhere

    // create a binding by code
    Binding passwordBinding = new Binding(SecurePasswordProperty.Name);
    passwordBinding.Source = myObject;
    passwordBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    // you can configure other binding stuff here
    MyPassword.SetBinding(SecurePasswordProperty, passwordBinding);
}

private void MyPassword_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // this should trigger binding and therefore validation
    ((MyObject)DataContext).SecurePassword = MyPassword.SecurePassword;
}
```

Comment: I do hope people realize the PasswordBox is itself insecure, since it will happily decrypt the password for any application that asks nicely.  Just attach to the process, and via reflection, say, "Hey PasswordBox, what's in the Password property?"  I get that you can get a little protection from memory scraping, specifically, by avoiding storing it in a string field, but for most use cases, it's already game over if *any* malicious payload has been installed--and perhaps not *really* worth fretting over.

Comment: @Daniel - SecureString's does not protect from a live debugger or similar live threats. A good explanation of handled threats is here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/05/27/making-strings-more-secure/ (also make sure you read comments from Shawn)